# How to join JSON with table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a master table with column names for example:

```js
Table name: user_attribute
---------------------------------
ColumnId    ColumnName
---------------------------------
1           Name
2           Email
3           Phone
```

Another table with JSON column example:

```js
Table name: user_detail
------------------------------------
UserId      UserInformation
------------------------------------
1     {"Name":"abc","Email":"abc@test.com","Phone":"23231233","Company":"test"}
2     {"Name":"xyz","Email":"xyz@test.com","Phone":"8909788","Location":"NA"}
```

I am trying to write a dynamic view which can show JSON information in tabular format but only those columns which are part of master table.

I can do it using JSON_VALUE function by hardconding json properties but I want to avoid that. So that anytime I add new value in master table "user_attribute", that should reflect in view.

Comment: Your snippets might look poshy, but they are completely useless, functionality-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a setup like this:

```
declare @attributes table (Id int identity(1,1), Name sysname);

insert into @attributes (Name)
values
('Name'),('Email'),('Phone');

declare @data table (
  UserId int,
  JData nvarchar(max)
);

insert into @data (UserId, JData)
values
(1, N'{"Name":"abc","Email":"abc@test.com","Phone":"23231233","Company":"test"}'),
(2, N'{"Name":"xyz","Email":"xyz@test.com","Phone":"8909788","Location":"NA"}');
```

, it is very easy to filter only necessary attributes from the JSON blob:

```
select d.UserId, ua.*
from @data d
  cross apply openjson(d.JData) ua
  inner join @attributes a on a.Name = ua.[key] collate database_default;
```

The `OPENJSON` function requires at least SQL Server 2016 to work.